# Magento 1.6.0.0: prevent PayPal Exporess altering my customers' shipping address

Tags: magento, paypal, street-address

When a customer places an order using alternate shipping address using PayPal Express, PayPal removes the shipping addresses company field and so it is written to the database.
I can't find any config option for that.

How do I prevent PayPal altering my customers shipping address ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can observe this https://github.com/onestepcheckout/PaypalRegister as it aims to perform the similar task you are after